# Proc http with https url

Tags: sas

So, I want to use Google Url shortener Api, and I try to use

```
proc http
```

so, when I run this code

```
filename req "D:\input.txt"; 
filename resp "D:\output.txt";

proc http 
url="https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url" 
method="POST"   
in=req         
ct="application/JSON" 
out=resp       
;run;
```

(where D:\input.txt looks like {"longUrl": "http://www.myurl.com"} ) everything works greate on my home SAS Base 9.3. But, at work, on EG 4.3, I get:

```
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

and no possible to debug. After googling, I found, that I have to set java system option like this

```
-jreoptions (-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=full-path-to-the-trust-store -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword)
```

But, where I can get "the certificate of the service to be trusted"- and password to it?

Edit: As I noticed in comments below, my work SAS installed into server, so I didn't have direct access to configuration. Also, It isn't good idea to change servers config. So, I try to google more, and found beautiful solution using cUrl, without X command (cause it block in my EG). Equivalent syntax is:

```
filename test pipe 'curl -X POST -d @D:\input.txt https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url --header "Content-Type:application/json"';

data _null_;
infile test missover lrecl= 32000;
input ;
file resp;
put _infile_;   
run;
```

Hope it help someone

Comment: Note that EG 4.3 is not exactly related to SAS version - it typically is SAS 9.2, though it could work with later versions or earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know - but proc http works on my EG 4.3 without problems with http base url

Comment: I understand, I'm just saying the more useful thing to communicate is SAS version, not EG version.

Comment: Ye, but at work I have only EG licensed, not Base. Such trap. Goal is to try to configure it, if possible

Comment: EG is only an interface.  You do have base licensed.  You may not be able to *run* it (it may be on a server), but EG version is unrelated to SAS version, which is what's relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is on server (and I could run only EG from my client machine).

Comment: Understood... you can run `proc setinit; run;` to find out what version of SAS the server is running.

Answer (score 2):

1. Where to get the certificate 
   Open the URL that you want the certificate from via Chrome. Click on the lock file in the URL bar, click on "details" tab and then click on "Save as file" in the bottom right. You will need to know what trust store you are going to use at this stage. See the following step.
2. The password and trust store is defined by you. It is in most cases nothing more than an encrypted zip file. There are a lot of tools out there that allow you to create a trust store, encrypt it and then import the certificates into it. The choice will depend on what OS you are using. There are some java based tools that OS independent, for example Portecle. It allows to define various trust stores on different OS and you can administer them remotely.

Regards,
Vasilij